# Copy client files when publishing

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild, asp.net-core-7.0

On a Net Core 7 web application I need to build a few client scripts (JS and LESS).

The scripts are in "./approot" and when I run the command `npm run build` this is done:

1. Build the files in "./approot" and save the output to "./approot/dist"
2. Delete the folder "./webroot" with all its contents.
3. Create a new "./webroot" and copy all files from "./approot/dist" to "./webroot"

So I have the following on project's .csproj file:

```
<Target Name="Build Client" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Exec Command="npm install" />
  <Exec Command="npm run build" />
  <ItemGroup> 
    <Content Include="webroot\**"> 
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
    </Content> 
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

When I publish the application steps (1) and (2) are done.

However the "./webroot" folder is not copied to publish folder.

So when I upload the web application to the server the client files are not found.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE** The only way I am able to make this work is using:

```
  <Target Name="Copy Webroot" BeforeTargets="AssignTargetPaths" DependsOnTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="npm run build" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="webroot/**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

I also kept the following so that Client is build when debugging:

```
<Target Name="Build Client" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Exec Command="npm install" />
  <Exec Command="npm run build" />
  <ItemGroup> 
    <Content Include="webroot\**"> 
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
    </Content> 
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

The problem is when I publish the application I see the client being build twice.

How to solve this?

Comment: Manipulating the files in the `wwwroot` folder in a target with `AfterTargets="Build"` should be enough to get the updated files to the `publish` folder's `wwwroot` folder. `Content` manipulation should not be necessary.
Does anything change when you use `BeforeTargets="Build"` instead?

Comment: A correction: I am now using wwwroot but renamed it to webroot using in `Program.cs`:  `WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions { Args = args, WebRootPath = "webroot" });

Comment: The files are not copied using `AfterTargets="Build"` or `BeforeTargets="Build"`

Comment: I added an update to my question and there is an option where I made it work but now it is building the client application twice. How can I avoid this?